# Sharpziplib InflaterInputStream.Read behavior when zero bytes

Tags: c#, inflate, .net-remoting, sharpziplib

I am working on a .Net Remoting Compression Sink using InflaterInputStream. I got the guidelines from a .Net Remoting book [here](http://books.google.com.ph/books?id=u83fhvSZBKkC&pg=PA364&lpg=PA364&dq=BinaryServerFormatterSink&source=bl&ots=GjlUeAHh__&sig=jqKkMvvpQzG6P8pGwH8LBix1oGw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PzTXUun4KMWikgWcu4HYCA&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=BinaryServerFormatterSink&f=false).

I am using binary as formatter and the issue I am encountering is when .Net binaryformatter calls the InflaterInputStream.Read(...) method it sometimes passes a zero length byte as the first parameter. The InflaterInputStream is not able to handle zero length byte and throws a "Don't know what to do" exception:

```
public override int Read(byte[] b, int off, int len)
        {
            for (;;) {
                int count;
                try {
                    count = inf.Inflate(b, off, len);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new SharpZipBaseException(e.ToString());
                }

                if (count > 0) {
                    return count;
                }

                if (inf.IsNeedingDictionary) {
                    throw new SharpZipBaseException("Need a dictionary");
                } else if (inf.IsFinished) {
                    return 0;
                } else if (inf.IsNeedingInput) {
                    Fill();
                } else {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Don't know what to do");
                }
            }
        }
```

I am planning to add a "if" code block on top of the method so that it checks first if byte is zero. If it's zero then it would just return 0 something like:

```
public override int Read(byte[] b, int off, int len)
        {
            //empty bytes should not go into Inflate method.
            if (b.Length == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
```

Would this be the most appropriate solution for this issue? The calls to this method are coming from the .Net BinaryFormatter so I just handled it in this class but I am not particularly sure if returning zero would have an effect on the BinaryFormatter.

Comment: What version of framework are you targetting? Remoting was incorporated into WCF a long time ago. WCF 4.5 actually provides GZip compression for the Binary encoder out of the box. Additionally, [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) is available since .NET 2.0. You can use this even if you don't want to use WCF

Comment: Regarding the actual question, it seems the code is your own and doesn't come from the book. What behavior do you want for the empty array case? The obvious thing would be to treat it as a finished operation and just return 0.

Comment: Is the code you provided your own or the source of SharpZipLib's InflaterInputStream? Even if this comes from the library, why are you passing around byte arrays instead of wrapping your own stream with InflaterInputStream? You may have encountered a usage not expected by its creators

Comment: @Panagiotis I am targeting .Net 3.5 but this is a legacy application using .Net Remoting and SharpZipLib that I could not change yet. Also, I've read reviews [link](http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2011/06/01/ode-to-sharpziplib/) that the sharpziplib provides better compression than GZipStream.

The code is not my own; The CompressionHelper.GetUncompressedStreamCopy method on the book calls the SharpZipLib which is an open source .Net implementation of Java's Gzip/zip compression.

Comment: @Panagiotis The behavior I want is just to make sure that the classes I sent over .Net Remoting would not be corrupted. When I send a message on .Net Remoting my client sink compresses the stream . Then .Net's BinaryClientFormatterSink reads the stream. It is the one that sends a zero array byte to the Read method. I just need to make sure that .Net is still able to read my stream correctly.